# Add AdWordsApi keys to App.config

Tags: vb.net, google-ads-api

I an developing a Windows form Application using VB. My software will connect to a SQL Database and to a Google Adwords API. The problem is when I try to Add the keys for the Adwords Api in the App.config file I get the following error: "Configuration system failed to initialize: AdWordsApi configuration section not recognized". I have read some examples about hoy to fill my Appconfig file but nothing seems to work. Could you help me know the proper way to do it? I leave here my App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
            <section name="ReporteExcel.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXX" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <AdWordsApi>
        <add key="MaskCredentials" value="true"/>
        <add key="EnableSoapExtension" value="true"/>
        <add key="EnableGzipCompression" value="true"/>
        <add key="IncludeUtilitiesInUserAgent" value="true"/>
        <add key="ProxyServer" value=""/>
        <add key="ProxyUser" value=""/>
        <add key="ProxyPassword" value=""/>
        <add key="ProxyDomain" value=""/>
        <add key="DeveloperToken" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
        <add key="GeneralClientCustomerId" value="XXX-XXX-XXXX"/>
        <add key="CanalDigitalClientCustomerId" value="XXX-XXX-XXXX"/>
        <add key="BanamexClientCustomerId" value="XXX-XXX-XXXX"/>
        <add key="AuthorizationMethod" value="OAuth2"/>
        <add key="OAuth2ClientId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"/>
        <add key="OAuth2ClientSecret" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX"/>
        <add key="OAuth2RefreshToken" value="1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-X"/>
        <add key="WebClientCustomerId" value="XXX-XXX-XXXX"/>
        <add key="SkipReportHeader" value="true"/>
        <add key="SkipReportSummary" value="true"/>
        <add key="SkipColumnHeader" value="false"/>
    </AdWordsApi>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ReporteExcel.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="sqlConnectionStr" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Data Source=192.168.2.1;Initial Catalog=CATALOG;User ID=ADMIN;Password=ADMIN;</value>
            </setting>
        </ReporteExcel.My.MySettings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Google.AdWords" publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXXXXX" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="18.33.0.0" newVersion="18.34.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Ads.Common" publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.17.0.0" newVersion="3.18.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it reads the file, the configSections act as a Table of Contents for the file
Try the following change and see if it will recognize it.  [taken from here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/UtzaqqbpqFc)

```
    <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                <section name="ReporteExcel.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXX" requirePermission="false"/>
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="AdWordsApi" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>     
 </configSections>
```

Comment: The line you specified didn't work exactly but you were right because I was missing the "section" specification in order for the config file to recognize the <AdWordsApi> tag. I used the following line
    `<section name="AdWordsApi" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>`

Comment: Excellent, and I've corrected answer to use this type!